# I find two different answers using Kirchoff's rules on single loop

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage, batteries

[image: Figure]

I found this question in a book asking for voltage $X$. I allowed them to use any method they want. I too after revision using kirchoff's loop rules am getting too different answers. Please help me to know where I am going wrong.

[image]

Comment: Please note that check-my-work questions are off-topic on this site. Also, please use MathJax to write equations rather than attaching pictures.

Comment: Thank you. I will fix it.

Answer (score 2):

> > Kirchhoff's Voltage Law states that the sum of voltage rises equals the sum of voltage drops around a loop.
>
> Source: [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/physics/circuits-topic/circuits-resistance/a/ee-kirchhoffs-laws)

> > - When a resistor is traversed in the same direction as the current, the change in potential is −IR.
> > - When a resistor is traversed in the direction opposite to the current, the change in potential is +IR.
> > - When an emf is traversed from – to + (the same direction it moves    positive charge), the change in potential is +emf.
> > - When an emf is traversed from + to – (opposite to the direction it    moves positive charge), the change in potential is − emf.
>
> Access for free at https://openstax.org/books/college-physics/pages/1-introduction-to-science-and-the-realm-of-physics-physical-quantities-and-units

Notice how in Method 1 you have considered the potential difference as "negative", while according to the scheme, it should be positive.
So, correctly, it would be:

$Method\ I: +2.2-1.4-X=0$ 
or 
$Method\ II: -2.2+1.4+X=0$ 
Therefore, $X = 0.8V$

Comment: @kanyarwanda-cyprien I have updated my answer for better clarity. Note that though you may perform your calculation of potential difference in either direction: clockwise or anti-clockwise, you can consider the direction of current only in compliance with what is the conventional direction, that is from positive end of the voltage source to the negative end.